# To use play framework, Do I have to pay intellij ultimate edition?

Tags: scala, playframework, ide, playframework-2.3

I am now struggling into specifying workspace for 'play for java'

In the first place, I choose eclipse luna, but it occurs error with twirl template engine.

it seemingly doesn't work in eclipse, but it works.

so, now i decide to use intellij, however intellij community edition can not use play framework with java, some people said to me 'use sublime text' but I don't want to use text editor, cause It doesn't support auto-import,

now, Do I have to pay for intellij ultimate edition for play development?

I am highschool student in korea, I can not pay ultimate edition, because I have no money.

Answer (score 4):

Play can absolutely be used with IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition. I frequently run a Play application with SBT on the command line, then edit my Scala and debug in IntelliJ CE. This won't be as "integrated" of a solution as you would get with Ultimate Edition (for example, the routes file won't have navigation integrated), but it is quite workable. A few tips:

1. In IntelliJ, make sure that you have the Scala plugin installed.
2. You can export an IDEA project from your SBT project with this SBT plugin: https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea
3. To enable debugging, launch sbt -jvm-debug=9999, as documented here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/PlayConsole
4. To debug from IntelliJ, create a remote run target that connects to localhost on port 9999, then click the debug toolbar button with SBT running in debug mode. [image: IntelliJ Remote Run Target Dialog]

Answer (score 2):

JetBrains will give you a one year license to IntelliJ if you can prove you are a student. Having a school email address is proof enough.

https://www.jetbrains.com/student/#faq

Answer (score 0):

JetBrains has an excellent student program. You can use all products for free (including intelliJ Ultimate). https://www.jetbrains.com/student/